# Using Protobuf in .Net Core with .proto files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nancy, protocol-buffers

I'm looking into using Protobuf to send data between my Microservices, and
I'm using the C# support in `Google.ProtoBuf` and not `ProtoBuf-Net`, since I want to compile classes from `.proto files`.

The reason for this is the Microservices are not strictly .Net. Some of the are written in `Go` etc.

I'm looking for something like the `ProtoBufFormatter` in the package `WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf`, but support `Google.ProtoBuf`.

The `ProtoBufFormatter` returns serialized protobuf data if the client have set content type to `application/x-protobuf`, otherwise `Json`.

How can I achieve something similar for `Google.ProtoBuf`? Further I'm also looking into find this kind of support for the Nancy Framework on .Net Core as well.

I have found this [link](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2009/07/protobuf-net-now-with-added-orcas.html) where it explains how to use protobuf files with Protobuf-Net, but does not seem up to date (.Net Core + VSCode).

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any solution for my use case with `Google.Protobuf`, so I used a custom `InputFormatter` and `OutputFormatter` like in [this](https://damienbod.com/2015/06/03/asp-net-5-mvc-6-custom-protobuf-formatters/) blog post, with `Protobuf-Net`.

Then to call and deserialize the protobuf content in the client, I came up with this solution:

```
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5002") };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/home");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {   
            if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/x-protobuf")
            {             
                using(var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    var protoBufModel = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<ProtobufModelDto>(stream);
                    return $"{protoBufModel.Name}, {protoBufModel.StringValue}, {protoBufModel.Id}";
                }
            }

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProtobufModelDto>(content);
            return $"{jsonModel.Name}, {jsonModel.StringValue}, {jsonModel.Id}";
        }

        return "Failed";
```

Next step will be to figure out how to create models from `.proto` files with `Protobuf-Net`.